# Can not remove white space starting of the string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have tried to remove the white space starting of the string in php. I have tried the following but there is no solution.

```
$str = ' test string';

var_dump($str); // outputs string(12) " test string"
```

if i give

```
var_dump($str[0]); // outputs string(1) ""
```

I have tried with `preg_replace` also but there is no use. It is removing the white space between `test and string` also . can anyone please help how to remove the white space at the starting of the string. can anyone give `regex` for removing white space only starting of the string

Note: `trim` also not working even `ltrim`

Comment: If you want to output the first character of a string, use `$str{0}` instead of `$str[0]`.

Comment: @thormeier, `$str[0]` works.

Comment: paste the code that you have tried here

Comment: @MichaelRushton I just noticed that, thank you... But I'd rather use `$str{0}`, because `$str[0]` indicates that you are using an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim) for removing whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.

```
echo ltrim('    test string');   // "test string"
```

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for removing from the end,  or [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove from both start and end of string.

```
echo rtrim('test string    ');   // "test string"
echo trim('   test string  ');   // "test string"
```

> I have tried with [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) also. It is removing the white space between test and string also...

- The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string.
- Similarly, `$` matches right after the last character in the string.

  To remove whitespace just from the beginning of the string:

  ```
  $str = preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $str);
  ```

  To remove whitespace from both beginning and end of string:

  ```
  $str = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/', '', $str);
  ```

Comment: Can you please tell me for end of the string

Comment: `rtrim` for the end; `trim` for both start and end.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/ltrim):

```
echo ltrim($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()`. Strings are indexed starting from 0, so make that 1, and the first char is gone.

```
$str = substr($str, 1);
echo $str
```

Answer (score 0):

`ltrim()` - Removes whitespace from the left side of a string

`rtrim()` - Removes whitespace from the right side of a string

`trim()`  - Removes whitespace from both sides of a string.